# Give an example of two languages that are not recognisable such that their union is recognisable?

Tags: formal-languages

I have this question:

Give an example of two languages that are not recognisable such that
their union is recognisable. Justify your answer (you are allowed to use
any properties of the class Rec $A^∗$ of recognisable languages over an
alphabet $A$).

i.e. $A \notin Rec A^*$ and $B \notin Rec A^*$ but $A \cup B \in Rec A^*$

Not quite sure how to answer it. I know I should provide my workings so far, but as it's simply "state an example", and I don't know an example, I find it hard to provide any workings...

Although I imagine it is something simple, like $A = {\phi}$ and $B = \{a\}$ or something?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This might just be because I'm unfamiliar with the terminology, but what exactly does "recognizable" mean?

Comment: My guess is that for any unrecognizable language, its complement is also not recognizable?

Comment: Yes, I think I noticed that recognisable is notated differently in different textbooks as I read other papers on the subject. Our module definition is "A recognisable language is a subset $L$ of $A^*$ such that $L=L(Z)$ for some DFA $Z$".

Comment: @Penguin47 That sounds very much like what I (from only learning about this stuff here on SE and on Wikipedia) would call a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Equivalent_formalisms). Does that seem right?

Comment: Yes, I believe they are all equivalent. Regular language = Rat $A^*$ = Rec $A^*$.

Comment: What's the union of a language and its complement?

Comment: @rici It equals $\phi^c$. How would we know this is recognisable, when $A$ and $A^c$ are not? Thanks. Can we simply state it is rational, therefore recognisable?

Comment: What is $\phi$ here? And is $A$ both an alphabet and a language? What does "'rational" mean in this context?

Comment: $\phi$ is the empty set. A is a language, not necessarily the alphabet (though maybe it has to be). Rational means the same thing as regular in this context.

Answer (score 1):

I found a great example elsewhere on this website [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2456191), but it took me a while to find it as it used different language to how I have studied it.

Let there be two languages, neither recognisable:

$$L_1 = [a^i b^j : j \leq i]$$ and $$L_2 = [a^i b^j : i < j]$$

Their union is:

$$L_1 \cup L_2 = [a^* b^*]$$ This is rational, therefore recognisable (by Kleene's Theorem).